# Laravel Homestead Environment variables from .env not accessible in the code

Tags: php, laravel, environment-variables, homestead

I am running Laravel using Homestead as a local development environment and running Linux and Apache in production.

For some reason, from the local homestead instance of the application, the `env("KEY")` helper returns `null` and does not recognize anything set in the `.env` file. It seems to work fine in production.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Is the local machine windows?

Comment: nope, using a mac, OS X

Comment: does `App::environment();` return anything?

Comment: `App::environment();` causes a 500

Comment: `App::environment();` returns `"local"` using artisan tinker